# How to select the result of one column from the query and use it as a filtering field in another query?

Tags: python, mysql

How to select the result of one column from the query and use it as a filtering field in another query?

Eg: `select col_1, col_2 from tablename;`

Here I need to take col_1 and feed this into another query as filtering.

Eg: `select * from tablename where col_1;`

Here the col_1 value has output of first query.

Comment: Sure, you can do that, because the second query is just a string until you prepare it as a query. You can concatenate strings together, right? But there is a risk that `col_1` does not contain a valid SQL expression, or worse, contains a valid SQL expression that does something you didn't intend. It's up to you to use it safely.

Comment: Have you considered using a JOIN or a WHERE Clause?